# UnityEngine.Networking.dll not found when building UWP App

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

I got a Unity Project using Unity.Networking for communication via the Network. Everything works fine in the Editor and when I build it as an Executable.

However, when I try to build it as a UWP I got following problem:

- building with Unity: `UnityEngin.Networking.dll was not found`
- building with VisualStudio: `UnityEngineNetworking.dll was not found`

Sure it can not be found, since the File is called `UnityEngine.Networking.dll`. Thats really strange because it is possible to build it as an Executable and I also never got such a problem building other Projact as UWP.

Does anyone ever got a similar problem?

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: 2017.3.0f3 is the Verison

Comment: It's still new and I smell  a bug. You should file for a bug report, This problem shouldn't be in 2017.1

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll report it!

Comment: Have you tried the latest build? How you choose your Build Type and SDK version. Maybe we can build a project and test it first, then we will be able to know whether we can reproduce it.